# Finding a point on a normal distribution knowing just two other points on it?

Tags: normal-distribution

So I have two known points on a normal distribution.  A 50th percentile point and a 75th percentile point.  How can I figure out what percentile a third point is at?

For instance:
50th percentile: 588.92
75th percentile: 719.92
 xth percentile: 725.02

An excel/libreoffice calc formula would be fantastic, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

HINT... The $50$th percentile is the mean $\mu$. You need to find $\sigma$, so get hold of a set of inverse $\Phi$ tables and use $\frac{712.92-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.75)$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Very ashamed to say it, but college maths were 25 years ago and I've forgotten nearly everything past trig.  My daughter's got a couple years before she's up to this so I'm just pounding the textbooks to relearn what I've lost. :(

Comment: Can you calculate $\sigma$?

Comment: No, but I can learn how.  I'll do a google search on calculating σ.  Was hoping it would be something I could just plug into excel (as I have to do this on a bunch of different data pairs without having the underlying data).  Is this possible without having the underlying raw data?

Comment: To find $\sigma$ you just have to look up $\Phi^{-1}(0.75)$ and rearrange the equation